# How set width and height attributes for <img> element within <picture> element to prevent layout shifts?

Tags: html, css

Running Lighthouse in Chrome DevTools it says CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift) needs improvement.

I’m aware that modern browsers now set the default aspect ratio of images based on an image's `width` and `height` attributes. Hence best practice is that `width` and `height` attributes **should be set** to prevent layout shifts.

Despite this, I have omitted setting the `width` and `height` attributes since this is the only way I can get it to work the way I want (please see my code below).

Because I’m having images in WebP format (with png fallbacks) I’m forced to use the `<picture>` element (so that the browsers not supporting WebP get the png version of the image). Please note I’m using differently-sized versions of the *same image*.

*Hence if I didn't have used WebP format I would go along with `<img>` solely and not `<picture>`. The problem would then have been solved thanks to the aspect ratio.*

As you can see in the code snippet below there are two versions of the *same image* in this particular example. Setting `width="245"` and `height="600"` in `<img>` result in both my two differently-sized versions of the *same image* getting the maximum size of 245 x 600px (it will of course scale down in accordance with smaller viewports). For wider viewports (min-width: 813px) according to my media query I'm serving the larger version of the *same image* but setting `width` and `height` in `<img>` the image scales down to 245 x 600px.

Now to my question/s; If possible, what can I do to be able to set the `width` and `height` attributes for my `<img>` element within my `<picture>` element to prevent layout shifts (and also get other benefits for doing so such as faster load times)? Hence, how do I get the browsers to make use of the aspect ratio to show my images the correct way?

I would really appreciate someone’s guidance with this.

Thanks / Carl

```
<picture>
            <source 
              media="(max-width: 812px)" 
              srcset="image-245w.webp"
              type="image/webp"
            >
            <source 
              media="(min-width: 813px)" 
              srcset="image-332w.webp"
              type="image/webp"
            >
            <source 
              media="(max-width: 812px)" 
              srcset="image-245w.png"
              type="image/png"
            >
            <source 
              media="(min-width: 813px)" 
              srcset="image-332w.png"
              type="image/png"
            >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="image-245w.png" alt="image">     
</picture>
```

Comment: well, technically speaking you have no height or width applied. You have no css in this snippet containing a height or width. and befor the edit you had the attribute: `width="600"` which is technically not working. 600 what? width = 600 bananas? tomatoes?... you need also name a unit like `px, vw/vh, em, %` ...

Comment: Hello, yes I omitted px in the text. Acutally you don't specify anything in the attributes 'width' and 'height'. Correct is width="245" height="600" without px, em or anyhing.

Comment: I found, that there is a `width` and `height` defined for the `<source>` in the HTML specs. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element. When used inside a `<picture>` element. But I didn’t test if this will work without CLS

Answer (score 1):

Allowing `width` and `height` attributes on `<source>` elements is now [in the spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20221102015927/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) and browsers are beginning to adopt it.

[GitHub Issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20220706235909/https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4968#issuecomment-790241902)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing and I came to the conclusion that using `width` and `height` (as you should) on the image element cancels out the `sizes` attribute. You can't get your responsive image to work properly anymore if you set the `width` and `height`.

I have created a small repo that shows different combinations: https://www.gijsvandam.nl/responsive-picture-element/

The solution to this is to *not* use `sizes` *if* you use `width` and `height` but instead depend on css for setting the correct width and height.

```html
<picture>
            <source 
              srcset="image-245w.webp 245w, image-332w.webp 332w"
              type="image/webp"
            >
            <img
              srcset="image-245w.png 245w, image-332w.png 332w" 
              class="img-fluid" 
              src="image-245w.png" 
              alt="image" 
              width="245" 
              height="600">     
</picture>
```

```css
     @media (max-width: 812px) {
        .img-fluid {
           width: 245px;
           height: auto;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 813px) {
        .img-fluid {
           width: 332px;
           height: auto;
        }
      }
```

It is important to understand that the `srcSet` in combination with `sizes` (or in combination with the css above) doesn't necessarily force the browser to use one image or the other. Depending on the `device pixel ratio` the browser may choose to load the bigger image to show in the 245px wide image slot. You just have to trust the browser that it will choose the best file for the job. There is not a one to one relationship between 'sizes' and `srcSet`. That's why you can provide more (or less) files in a `srcSet` than there are options in the `sizes` attribute.

Comment: But how can the browser select the most appropriate image if you remove "sizes"? Isn't "sizes" telling the browser that "for screen sizes x the picture will be shown with width y", and then the browser can select the most appropriate size to download?

Comment: @ErikH Yes, but if you leave the sizes argument out, the browser can still (and will) use the CSS to determine the width of the image and figure out the most appropriate file to download, based on that. But this *does* have a significant downside. The browser has to parse the CSS before it can start downloading the most appropriate file. With the `sizes` attribute available the browser can start downloading right away.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @gijswijs. So, are you recommending to keep `sizes`, or not?

Comment: I think it depends on your situation. If SEO ranking is important, I would not use `sizes` and instead use 'height' and 'width' so that you score higher on *Pagespeed Insights* which is a factor in the SEO ranking. If SEO ranking is not important, I would use `sizes`.

Answer (score 0):

ex-
img.d-blocks,img.d-block_w-100,img.d-block-w-100{
max-width :20%

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 812px) {
    .img-fluid {
       width: 245px;
       height: auto;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 813px) {
    .img-fluid {
       width: 332px;
       height: auto;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the gist of your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* displays the image at 245x600px for small screens */

@media only screen
  and (max-width: /*enter a width in px */) {
    .img-fluid {
      height: 245px;
      width: 600px;
    }
}

/* displays the image at 332x812px for small screens */

@media only screen
  and (min-width: /*enter a width of max-width +1px*/) {
    .img-fluid {
      height: 332px;
      width: 812px;
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="image-245w.png" alt="image">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score -1):

What ever you try to do, its way to complicated thatw ay you try to accoplish it. You can use the very same image and resize it with CSS. Use media queries to declare different sizes of the image depending on the screen width like shown below.

```css
/* displays the image at 245x600px for small screens */

@media only screen
  and (max-width: /*enter a width in px */) {
    .img-fluid {
      height: 245px;
      width: 600px;
    }
}

/* displays the image at 332x812px for small screens */

@media only screen
  and (min-width: /*enter a width of max-width +1px*/) {
    .img-fluid {
      height: 332px;
      width: 812px;
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="image-245w.png" alt="image">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! This is actually exactly what I do in my code above. By omitting the width and height attributes in <img> I rely on my media queries. It works perfectly fine BUT I will receive CLS by omitting them as you will with your code I believe. You will want to add these attributes nowadays to avoid CLS, question is how to do it within a <picture> element?

Comment: *Also I'm servering differently-sized versions of the same image in a responsive way not resizing one image for differnet viewports. That will cost bandwith.

Comment: resizing image doesnt cost bandwidth. serving multiple images does because then multiple images have to be laoded. reiszing the image with css cost only loading the image once. For example if you switch a smartphone from portrait to landscape, the image will be reloaded the way you do it.

Comment: Yes it does cost bandwith serving only one image. Imagine you have one huge image to be shown on cinemas and also on smartphones. This image is HEAVY. Showing this image on smartphones (massively downsizing it) is not a good idea since it is the same heavy image as for cinemas and hence will cost a lot more bandwith than giving the smartphone a smaller/lighter version of the same image. Serving serveral images doesn't equal that all are used/loaded. Only those images necessary for the conditions set up (media queries) will be shown.